# How to send another modal after completing one

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, webhooks

I'm trying to make an applications system for a friend of mine but the form is longer then the maximum modal questions (which is 5) so I divided it in multiple parts and now I'm trying to send a message with a button containing the next part

-edit
the problem is only occurring when I try to do the second part because I tried with different part and then it worked so there is something in applicationmodal2 that is not working

-edit 2
I found out it's because I have something that is too long and I need to shorten to 45 characters (or words I'm not sure) but I can't find out which the things are I need to shorten

here is a part of the code

```
# --- part 2 ---
class ApplicationModal2(discord.ui.Modal, title="Application part 2"):

    ActivityScale = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="1. How active are you on scale from 1-10",
        placeholder="Enter a number between 1-10 that describes your activity",
        max_length=2,
        required=True
    )

    PvpScale = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="2. How good would you describe yourself at pvp on a scale from 1-10",
        placeholder="Enter a number between 1-10 that describes your pvp skills",
        max_length=2,
        required=True
    )

    TimeZone= discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="3. What timezone do you live in",
        placeholder="If you don't know look it up on Google",
        max_length=5,
        required=True
    )

    Listening = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="4. Are you a good listener",
        placeholder="Fill in yes or no",
        max_length=3,
        required=True
    )

    Training = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="5. Do you realize you have to go through training to get in",
        placeholder="Fill in yes or no",
        max_length=3,
        required=True
    )

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        channel = interaction.channel

        app_embed2 = discord.Embed(
          title=None,
          description=None,
          colour=0xBA0000
        )
      
        embed.add_field(
          name="Activity Scale",
          value=self.ActivityScale.value
        )

        embed.add_field(
          name="PVP Scale",
          value=self.PvpScale.value
        )

        embed.add_field(
          name="Timezone",
          value=self.TimeZone.value
        )

        embed.add_field(
          name="Good listener",
          value=self.Listening.value
        )

        embed.add_field(
          name="Realise going trough training",
          value=self.training.value
        )

      
      
        await interaction.response.send_message("Thank you for filling in the second part of your application.", ephemeral=True)

    async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error : Exception):
        traceback.print_tb(error.__traceback__)


# --- part 1 ---
class ApplicationModal(discord.ui.Modal, title="Application part 1"):
     
    RobloxUsername = discord.ui.TextInput(
        style=discord.TextStyle.short,
        label="Roblox username",
        placeholder="Enter your roblox username",
        max_length=30,
        required=True
    )

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        channel = interaction.channel

        app_embed = discord.Embed(
          title=f"{interaction.user.name}'s application",
          description=f"<@{interaction.user.id}> applied for 'div'",
          colour=0xBA0000
        )

        app_embed.set_author(
          name=f"Filled in by: {interaction.user.name}",
          icon_url=interaction.user.display_avatar.url
        )

        app_embed.add_field(
          name="Roblox Username",
          value=self.RobloxUsername.value
        )
          
        await channel.send(embed=app_embed)
        
        #trying to get second modal
        async def app_modal_2(interaction):
            application_modal_2 = ApplicationModal2()
            application_modal_2.user = interaction.user
            #LINE BELOW THIS IS ERROR
            await interaction.response.send_modal(application_modal_2)
        
        part2 = Button(label="Second part")
        part2.callback = app_modal_2
        view = View(timeout=None)
        view.add_item(part2)

        await interaction.response.send_message(view=view, ephemeral=True)
   
    async def on_error(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, error : Exception):
        traceback.print_tb(error.__traceback__)

#getting first modal (WORKING)
@bot.tree.command()
async def apply(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    application_modal = ApplicationModal()
    application_modal.user = interaction.user
    await interaction.response.send_modal(application_modal)
```

since its the same thing I used for the command I thought it would work but I keep getting this error

```
2023-08-11 09:57:48 ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <View timeout=900.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2> url=None disabled=False label='Second part' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Ticket-bot-TWW-Faction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 219, in app_modal_2
    await interaction.response.send_modal(application_modal_2)
  File "/home/runner/Ticket-bot-TWW-Faction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 972, in send_modal
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "/home/runner/Ticket-bot-TWW-Faction/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/webhook/async_.py", line 221, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In data.components.1.components.0.label: Must be 45 or fewer in length.
In data.components.4.components.0.label: Must be 45 or fewer in length.
```

anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Discord API limitation. You cannot send a modal as a response in the callback of another modal. I suggest you add a checkpoint between the modals, with a button that the user can click and proceed to the next modal.

Comment: thats what i tried in this code 
i call a button as response but when i press the button i get error as well

Comment: @Arqade, just read your error message:  `In data.components.1.components.0.label: Must be 45 or fewer in length.`
You are using a label with more than 45 characters.

Comment: yea i alr found out but i forgot python starts counting at 0 so i was confused wich one i needed to change bu ty